# How is the type of `([] ==) []` inferred  haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, type-systems

It sounds silly, but I can't get it. Why can the expression [] == [] be typed at all? More specifically, which type (in class Eq) is inferred to the type of list elements?

In a ghci session, I see the following:

```
Prelude> :t (==[])
(==[]) :: (Eq [a]) => [a] -> Bool
```

But the constraint `Eq [a]` implies `Eq a` also, as is shown here:

```
Prelude> (==[]) ([]::[IO ()])

<interactive>:1:1:
No instance for (Eq (IO ()))
  arising from use of `==' at <interactive>:1:1-2
Probable fix: add an instance declaration for (Eq (IO ()))
In the definition of `it': it = (== []) ([] :: [IO ()])
```

Thus, in []==[], the type checker must assume that the list element is some type a that is in class Eq. But which one? The type of [] is just [a], and this is certainly more general than Eq a => [a].

IMHO this should by ambiguous, at least in Haskell 98 (which is what we are talking about)

Comment: With GHC (not GHCi) I've got `Ambiguous type variable \`a' in the constraint \`Eq a' arising from a use of \`=='`

Comment: @Kenny - yes thats what I expected before I tried in ghci - the greater my surprise. Thanks for the hint, now my world order is restored :)

Comment: It's interesting Hugs gives the expression `[] == []` type `Eq a => Bool`.

Comment: Sorry for "necroposting", but there is no way to specify the context for `[] == []` is there? Without specializing `[]` themselves.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

GHCi has [extended rules for type defaulting,](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12-latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules) which is what tripped you up. In this case, I believe it would default the ambiguous type to `()`. The subtle ways that GHCi behaves differently are nice for the sake of better interactivity, but they do occasionally result in confusion...

Comment: @camccann: run `ghci -Wall`. then `[] == []` gets `Warning: Defaulting the following constraint(s) to type '()'`

Comment: The extended defaulting only matters when you want to show or run the code. The :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool type is entirely correct.

Comment: @Don Stewart: That type is of course fine--I think what confused Ingo is rather `([] == []) :: Bool`, where the ambiguous `Eq a` constraint is satisfied by defaulting to `()`, as yairchu demonstrated.

Comment: Certainly,  that's defaulting at work. But his initial type appears wrong-- there's no Eq [a] constraint.

Comment: @Don Stewart: Ah, I didn't even notice that. I'd guess that as a typo, since that's obviously not what GHCi would report. Maybe he's using Windows and copy-paste from a terminal window doesn't work well.

Comment: @Don - Yes, constraint as per ghci is Eq [a], not Eq a. Which is fine as (==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool

Comment: @Ingo: Really? It ought to simplify that to just an `Eq a` constraint. What version of GHC are you using?

Comment: @camccann 6.4.2.
But for me this is ok, as (==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
One substitution [b] for a, and we get the above.
Yet, the constraint for b that arises is not shown, perhaps because it is implied?

Comment: @Ingo: Wow, that's an ancient version of GHC.

Comment: @Kenny: It appears that "ancient" nowadays means "more than half a year old"? :)

Comment: Anyway, it's at least 2008, so it should cover the 98 standard very well.

Comment: @Ingo: Hehe. (Actually [GHC 6.4.2 is released in 2006](http://haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_642.html), i.e. 4 years ago. The current version is 6.12.2, i.e. 4 major versions apart.)

Answer (score 1):

GHC infers the most general type:

> (==[]) :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool

It should be read as:

- if you have an instance of Eq a,
- then Haskell can give you a function from lists of those 'a's to Bool

So yes, the implication here is that you have an instance of Eq for elements of the list, and GHC already has an instance for lists in general (relying on Eq for the elements), so we get a nice general type.

The type checker "assumes" you can supply an Eq a instance when called at a particular type.

I can't reproduce your results of having a `Eq [a]` constraint.

Comment: though Kenny above got different results with GHC. Note: We are talking haskell 98, I am sure some fancy GHC extensions are clever enough to type it correctly, yet I still do not understand how exactly. IMHO, this is really an ambiguous case.

Comment: @Ingo: `(== [])` isn't ambiguous, just polymorphic as usual; it will work the same (and correctly) in GHCi or otherwise. As for GHC extensions, you can enable the same extended defaulting that GHCi uses, but I don't know why you'd want to...

Comment: @Don: Perhaps you have different version/flags? As for me:
X:\fc3>ghci
   ___         ___ _
      / _ \ /\  /\/ __(_)
     / /_\// /_/ / /  | |      GHC Interactive, version 6.4.2, for  Haskell 98.
    / /_\\/ __  / /___| |      http://www.haskell.org/ghc/
    \____/\/ /_/\____/|_|      Type :? for help.
    
    Loading package base-1.0 ... linking ... done.
    Prelude> :t (==[])
    (==[]) :: (Eq [a]) => [a] -> Bool
    Prelude>

Comment: @Ingo: Wow, retro! Do you have shag carpet and listen to disco, too? :) Seriously, newer versions have nice features, why not upgrade...

Comment: GHC 6.4.2 was released was released 5 years ago. We're at GHC 6.12.2 now.

Comment: Weird that several people over the last few days have been using 6.4 or 6.6.  I googled for "GHC", and the first result is... "download ghc 6.12".  So I have no idea where people are getting this from...

Comment: Hunh. If I google for "download haskell compiler" or "download GHC" it decides to show links to download pages for GHC 6.6.1 and 6.2.1 (!) respectively.

Comment: @Don Stewart: http://i.imgur.com/Bz0DR.png Those aren't unreasonable search terms, are they...? I don't even know...