# Why do 3 and x (which was assigned 3) have different inferred types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, type-inference, monomorphism-restriction

Type inference in Haskell has a bit of a learning curve (to say the least!). A good way to start learning it is with simple examples. So, the following is a bit of a "hello world" for type inference.

Consider the following example:

```
Prelude> :t 3
3 :: (Num t) => t
Prelude> let x = 3
Prelude> :t x
x :: Integer
```

The question is thus: **Why do 3 and x have different types?**

**Link Summary:**

Read the answers below for the full story; here's just a link summary:

1. GHC type defaulting: [Haskell Report section
   4.3.4](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html)
2. GHCi's extended type defaulting: [Using GHCi section
   2.4.5](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.4/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules)
3. Monomorphic Restriction: [Haskell
   wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction)

Comment: Yes, the new title is much more specific/clearer than the old one!

Comment: I removed the bottom part of my original question; wasn't adding enough value to warrant inclusion.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's another factor here, mentioned in some of the links which acfoltzer includes, but it might be worth making explicit here. You're encountering the effect of the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction). When you say

```
let x = 5
```

you make a *top-level* definition of a *variable*. The MR insists that such definitions, when otherwise unaccompanied by a type signature, should be specialized to a monomorphic value by choosing (hopefully) suitable default instances for the unresolved type variables. By contrast, when you use `:t` to ask for an inferred type, no such restriction or defaulting is imposed. So

```
> :t 3
3 :: (Num t) => t
```

because `3` is indeed overloaded: it is admitted by any numeric type. The defaulting rules choose `Integer` as the default numeric type, so

```
> let x = 3
> :t x
x :: Integer
```

But now let's switch off the MR.

```
> :set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
> let y = 3
> :t y
y :: (Num t) => t
```

Without the MR, the definition is just as polymorphic as it can be, just as overloaded as `3`. Just checking...

```
> :t y * (2.5 :: Float)
y * (2.5 :: Float) :: Float
> :t y * (3 :: Int)
y * (3 :: Int) :: Int
```

Note that the polymorphic `y = 3` is being differently specialized in these uses, according to the `fromInteger` method supplied with the relevant `Num` instance. That is, `y` is not associated with a particular representation of `3`, but rather a scheme for constructing representations of `3`. Naïvely compiled, that's a recipe for slow, which some people cite as a motivation for the MR.

I'm (locally pretending to be) neutral on the debate about whether the monomorphism restriction is a lesser or greater evil. I always write type signatures for top-level definitions, so there is no ambiguity about what I'm trying to achieve and the MR is beside the point.

When trying to learn how the type system works, it's really useful to separate the aspects of type inference which

1. ‘follow the plan’, specializing polymorphic definitions to particular use cases: a fairly robust matter of constraint-solving, requiring basic unification and instance resolution by backchaining; and
2. ‘guess the plan’, generalizing types to assign a polymorphic type scheme to a definition with no type signature: that's quite fragile, and the more you move past the basic Hindley-Milner discipline, with type classes, with higher-rank polymorphism, with GADTs, the stranger things become.

It's good to learn how the first works, and to understand why the second is difficult. Much of the weirdness in type inference is associated with the second, and with heuristics like the monomorphism restriction trying to deliver useful default behaviour in the face of ambiguity.

Comment: Whatever your opinion about MR for compiled programs, everyone seems to agree that it should not be in effect by default at the GHCi prompt as in this example. [GHC bug #3202](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3202) fixes this. It was scheduled to be in 7.2.1 which was just released, but it looks like it didn't make it in. Hopefully it will be fixed in the next version of GHC.

Comment: @Yitz That would indeed be a good outcome. I'd be inclined to say that the MR should be off by default, but it would be good to gather hard data about how many type/performance problems that would introduce in the existing codebase. I also wonder whether GHC's specialization machinery might allow us to have it both ways. But I speculate.

Comment: "The MR insists that such definitions, when otherwise unaccompanied by a type signature, should be specialized to a monomorphic value" I've been trying to understand the MR for a while now, but still not quite there... I could understand if MR forced you to specify a signature, but simply defaulting to some type seems like the worst choice to me.

Answer (score 6):

This occurs because of [type defaulting in GHCi](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.4/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules), as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884364/how-is-the-type-of-inferred-haskell), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328682/int-vs-integer-in-class-instance), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887244/haskells-type-inference-strangeness), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283681/why-is-ghci-typing-this-statement-oddly), among others. Unfortunately this seems like something that is difficult to search for, since there are lots of ways to describe this behavior before you know the phrase "type defaulting".

**Update**: D'oh. Removed poor example.

Comment: Ehrm, this answer is pretty misleading. It would be perfectly fine for `x` to have the type `Num a => a`. As a matter of fact if you disable the monomorphism restriction or explicitly give `x` this type, it will have that type. And in that case there's nothing bogus about doing `x * 3.0`. Also defaulting for numeric types isn't ghci-specific.

Comment: @sepp2k: gah, the monomorphism restriction strikes even when I try to answer questions! You're exactly right.

Comment: @sepp2k: Thanks for the connection between type inference and type defaulting! I agree, searching for the former doesn't necessarily uncover the latter.

Answer (score 4):

Since nobody else has mentioned *why* there's a monomorphism restriction, I thought I'd add this bit from [A History of Haskell: Being Lazy With Class](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/history-of-haskell/history.pdf).

> 6.2 The monomorphism restriction A major source of controversy in the early stages was the so-called “monomorphism restriction.” Suppose
>   that genericLength has this overloaded type:
>
> ```
> genericLength :: Num a => [b] -> a
> ```
>
> Now consider this deﬁnition:
>
> ```
> f xs = (len, len) 
>      where len = genericLength xs
> ```
>
> It looks as if `len` should be computed only once, but
>   it can actually be computed twice. Why? Because we can infer the type
>   `len :: (Num a) => a`; when desugared with the dictionary-passing
>   translation, `len` becomes a function that is called once for each
>   occurrence of `len`, each of which might used at a different type.
>
> Hughes argued strongly that it was unacceptable to silently duplicate
>   computation in this way. His argument was motivated by a program he
>   had written that ran exponentially slower than he expected. (This was
>   admittedly with a very simple compiler, but we were reluctant to make
>   performance differences as big as this dependent on compiler
>   optimisations.)
>
> Following much debate, the committee adopted the
>   now-notorious monomorphism restriction. Stated brieﬂy, it says that a
>   deﬁnition that does not look like a function (i.e. has no arguments on
>   the left-hand side) should be monomorphic in any overloaded type
>   variables. In this example, the rule forces `len` to be used at the same
>   type at both its occurrences, which solves the performance problem.
>   The programmer can supply an explicit type signature for `len` if
>   polymorphic behaviour is required.
>
> The monomorphism restriction is
>   manifestly a wart on the language. It seems to bite every new Haskell
>   programmer by giving rise to an unexpected or obscure error message.
>   There has been much discussion of alternatives.  The Glasgow Haskell Compiler
>   (GHC, Section 9.1) provides a ﬂag:
>
> ```
> -fno-monomorphism-restriction
> ```
>
> to suppress the restriction altogether. But in all this time, no truly
>   satisfactory alternative has evolved.

I find the tone of the paper towards the monomorphism restriction is very interesting.