# Inconsistent behavior with fromIntegral in GHCi

Tags: haskell, types, ghci

I was hoping someone could explain the following behavior in GHCi, when using the function fromIntegral:

```
Prelude> let x = 1 :: Integer                                                                                                                                                    
Prelude> :t x                                                                                                                                                                    
x :: Integer                                                                                                                                                                     
Prelude> sqrt $ fromIntegral x                                                                                                                                                   
1.0                                                                                                                                                                              
Prelude> let y = fromIntegral x                                                                                                                                                  
Prelude> sqrt y                                                                                                                                                                  

<interactive>:181:1:                                                                                                                                                             
No instance for (Floating Integer)                                                                                                                                           
  arising from a use of `sqrt'                                                                                                                                               
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Floating Integer)                                                                                                             
In the expression: sqrt y                                                                                                                                                    
In an equation for `it': it = sqrt y
```

Why does it matter whether I set `y` and then take its `sqrt` or just directly take the `sqrt`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do 3 and x (which was assigned 3) have different inferred types in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055146/why-do-3-and-x-which-was-assigned-3-have-different-inferred-types-in-haskell)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`fromIntegral` is polymorphic in its return type. So the type of `y` in your code could be expected to be `Num a => a`. This type would allow you to use `y` as the argument to `sqrt` without problem.

However due to the monomorphism restriction, the type of `y` is not allowed to be polymorphic. Therefore it is defaulted to the default Num type, which is `Integer`.

When you do `sqrt $ fromIntegral x` the monomorphism restriction does not apply because it only applies to global variables and you don't store the result of `fromIntegral` in a variable this time.

You can fix this issue by either adding a type signature to y (`let y :: Num a => a; y = fromIntegal x`) or by disabling the monomorphism restriction.

Comment: To turn off the restriction, add `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` to the top of a file, or enter `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` in GHCi.

Comment: It is generally considered a good idea to put `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` in your .ghci since it is mostly a pain in the REPL. Using it in one of your program is less often necessary and not always a good idea (since it can interfere with sharing).