# Type signatures for Values

Tags: haskell

I struggled for hours to get something like the following right:

```
to_xyz_regular :: (RealFrac t) => (RegularSpd t) -> (t, t, t)
to_xyz_regular spd@(RegularSpd lambda_min lambda_max spectrum delta inverse_delta) =  
    let
        l = length cie_x - 1
        il = 1.0 / fromIntegral l
        samp i = sample spd $ lambda_min + inverse_delta * fromIntegral i
        integrate curve = (foldr (+) 0 $
                           map (\i -> curve!!i * samp i) [0..l]) * il
    in (integrate cie_x, integrate cie_y, integrate cie_z)
```

(this is a conversion routine from color SPDs / spectra to XYZ colors).

The values `cie_XXX` were defined as follows:

```
cie_start = 360.0
cie_end = 830.0
cie_x = [0.0001299000, 0.0001458470, 0.0001638021, 0.0001840037,
         ....]
cie_y = ....
cie_z = ....
```

but then giving me roughly

```
Could not deduce (t ~ Double)
from the context (RealFrac t)
....
```

the problem being that the `cie_XXX` values where stored as `Double`, where I really would have liked them being poylmorphic.

The solution I finally found was to add type signatures for those values:

```
cie_start :: (RealFrac t) => t
cie_end :: (RealFrac t) => t
cie_x :: (RealFrac t) => [t]
cie_y :: (RealFrac t) => [t]
cie_z :: (RealFrac t) => [t]
```

Now my question is: Is this the proper way to have polymorphic values/literals in Haskell?

---

*It was a bit tough for me to find a solution on websearch, because books, tutorials etc. mention type signatures only for parametric functions -> Are values just parameterless functions?*

Comment: If you want to leave the signatures off, you could disable [the monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction).

Comment: "Are values just parameterless functions?"  No, [not everything is a function in Haskell.](http://web.archive.org/web/20111211020433/http://conal.net/blog/posts/everything-is-a-function-in-haskell)  But, under the hood, any value with a type of the form `C => A` is a function from `C_Dict -> A`; [the monomorphism restriction exists because this might unexpectedly reduce sharing/increase computation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12979513/237428).  (Also, sorry about the Wayback Machine link above, but Conal Elliott's site seems to be down at the moment.)

Comment: Very insightful comments, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you have chosen is the proper way to have polymorphic types for numeric literals in Haskell.

The reason `Double` was selected for the type of `cie_XXX` is due to Haskell's defaulting mechanism (which is described in greater detail [here](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4)).  Defaulting is invoked when an otherwise polymorphic type (contains a `forall`, either implicitly or explicitly) is required to be monomorphic by the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) *or* the type is ambiguous (contains type variables that appears only to the left of `=>`, e.g. `a` in `(Read a, Show a) => String`), *and* the type is constrained to be an instance of a `Prelude` or standard library defined subclass of `Num`.  Defaulting forces the type to be unified with each entry in `default (...)` (starting with the left-most entry) until unification succeeds.  The default `default (...)` is

```
default (Integer, Double)
```

If for some reason `Float` is the desired default for real numbers,

```
default (Integer, Float)
```

could be defined.  If `Float` is the desired default for all numbers,

```
default (Float)
```

could be defined.

In the case of the original scenario,

```
cie_start :: Fractional a => a
```

is the most general type for `cie_start` (as well as `cie_end`).  This type, when inferred, would violate the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction).  However, in the presence of defaulting, a few types are first tried in the place of the type variable `a`.  Given that the default `default (...)` is `default (Integer, Double)`, `Integer` and `Double` are tried, in that order.

```
cie_start :: Fractional Integer => Integer
```

results in a constraint violation (`Integer` is not an instance of `Fractional`).

```
cie_start :: Fractional Double => Double
```

succeeds, and is simplified to

```
cie_start :: Double
```

To make the original scenario an error instead of defaulting to `Double` (and also disable defaulting entirely), add

```
default ()
```

at the top level of the module where `cie_XXX` are defined.

To make the scenario not require an explicit type signature and instead infer the most general type, add

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

to the top of the module where `cie_XXX` are defined (see [Monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) for more details about why this most general type is not used by default).

Overall, the method you have chosen to resolve this issue (adding an explicit type signature) is the best solution.  It is considered a best practice to have type signatures on all top level definitions.

Comment: In your introduction (2nd para) you say that defaulting is invoked by ambiguous types (which is true) but in the context of this question you might point out at the same time that it is also invoked by the monomorphism restriction. You can probably make the case the monomorphism restriction is a special case of ambiguous types but it's not entirely obvious...

Comment: I have reworded it some and added additional details.  I am having trouble wording it well, though.  Let me know if it is unclear (or incorrect).